# How to change animation duration in Odometer/vue-odometer

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Based on the `Odometer` doc https://github.hubspot.com/odometer/

> duration: 3000, // Change how long the javascript expects the CSS animation to take

My code as follow but the `duration` is not working:

```
 <IOdometer auto="false" class="iOdometer" :duration="10000" :value="f_value" format="d" />
```

Any ways to set the animation duration ?

Comment: you've shown a link that has nothing to do with vuejs as far as i can tell, so How have you gone from that library to something that looks like a vue component that you've created (I assume)

Comment: I guess it's https://github.com/xlsdg/vue-odometer

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue with Odometer itself, not the [Vue wrapper](https://github.com/xlsdg/vue-odometer) you are using.

Unfortunately Odometer documentation is not very clear about this but you need to change it on multiple places - JavaScript (that's what `duration` prop does) **and** CSS

See [this issue](https://github.com/HubSpot/odometer/issues/91)

Add this into your CSS:

```css
.odometer.odometer-animating-up .odometer-ribbon-inner, .odometer.odometer-animating-down.odometer-animating .odometer-ribbon-inner {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 10s !important;
    -moz-transition-duration: 10s !important;
    -ms-transition-duration: 10s !important;
    -o-transition-duration: 10s !important;
    transition-duration: 10s !important
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MichalLevy/u1ta8vqf/5/)

Comment: I had tried this, but not sure whether its the vue wrapper issue, it made the whole animation very lagging

Comment: Vue wrapper has nothing to do with it. It is really only tiny wrapper without any additional functionality. Runs just fine on my machine (tried with Vue too). See linked demo. Anyway this is only way how to change duration of animation...